# trapezoid transform graphics for java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [square to trapezoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157886/square-to-trapezoid)

Here is what i want to do. I'm currently drawing with Awt librairy and use the paintComponent method to draw (a grid for example). I draw colors, lines, images, etc. What i want to do is to take the **Graphics g parameter of paintComponent and apply a trapezoid-like transformation** after all my draw methods. My result will simulate a grid in space in 3D:

```
     --------
    - - - -  -
   -  - -  -  -
  -  -  -   -  -
 ----------------
```

like this.

Note: I don't want to draw a trapeze, or draw a rectangle into a trapeze. This won't work for me. And i'm open to change librairy (swing or whatever).
I'v been searching for quite a while and i haven't found any example about this, clear enough at least for me to understand.
Any tips, links? Thanks.

edit: I'm drawing in a JPanel

Comment: It's simple. Create a *normal* grid say at y = 0, and position the camera.

Comment: I'm not using 3D, I'm simulating it­.

Comment: I don't know the actual math/setup involved, but if you're using a `Graphics2D`, I'm guessing you need to use `Graphics2D.transform(AfflineTransform)`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse AffineTransform maintains parallelness and straightness. Obviously this transformation does not maintain parallelness so an AffineTransform won't enable this feature.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Guillaume is correct; [`javax.media.jai.PerspectiveTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html) may be an alternative. See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6157886/230513).